How can I make sure my function is not overcounting the number of words?
I'm writing a function to count the number of words in a user-inputted string of text. Currently I've set it up for word_count to increment every time it hits a space or punctuation mark, but I know that's not right as it'll increment twice when it gets to the end of a sentence. It'll also increment when it hits an apostrophe or hyphen within a word.
I think I need to either modify my for loop to treat a word as a sequence of characters followed by a space or punctuation mark (but not an apostrophe or hyphen), and/or somehow look ahead in the string to see if there's another space/punctuation mark coming next, and then not increment word_count again in that case. But I'm not sure how to do either of those things (or if there's a better way altogether).
I'm a complete beginner and doing this exercise as part of CS50's Week 2 Readability problem set. I don't want the final answer — just some clues please! Thanks in advance.
    int count_words(string text)
    {
        int length = strlen(text);
        int word_count = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (isspace(text[i]) || ispunct(text[i])) word_count++;
        }
        return word_count;
    }

If I input "This should be 8 words. But it isn't." it should return 8 words. Instead it returns 10.

How do you get the input? Is the newline included in the input? How do you handle sentences with multiple spaces or punctuation following each other? Or with a space after the punctuation, which is very common (just read your own question for a great example of that).

@Someprogrammerdude This is how I'm getting the text:
// Prompt the user to enter text     string text;     do     {         text = get_string("Text: ");     }     while (strcmp(text, "") == 0);
And my question is how best to handle a space followed by a punctuation at the end of the sentence.

Use a debugger to look at the actual contents of the strings. As for only worrying about the end, in the example sentence you have this part: "words. But" Your code will increase word_count on the dot '.' and on the space ' '. Perhaps it's not a problem with the end of the line, but rather this dot followed by a space that is your actual problem? Like I said, use a debugger to actually know what's going on.

Also, isn't a single quote '\'' also a punctuation character? Then the one in "isn't" will also increase the word count.

@Someprogrammerdude Yes. As I said “increment every time it hits a space or punctuation mark, but I know that's not right as it'll increment twice when it gets to the end of a sentence. It'll also increment when it hits an apostrophe or hyphen within a word.” I already know that my function is incorrect — I’m seeking advice on how to improve it to handle punctuation followed by a space, and how to handle punctuation within a word, such as an apostrophe or hyphen. I understand why I’m getting the results I’m getting. I just don’t know how to change my function to get the desired result.

While not really good, [the answer by kick54 is the way to go. Use two states: "In word", and "not in word", and count the number of transitions from "in word" to "out of word". Remember to track the end of the string (the null-terminator) as "out of word", so you can handle sentences that forgets the last terminating dot.

@Someprogrammerdude Just read your last comment... Seems kick54's solution is really not good. "off by one" problems... On the other hand, my answer below that looks for the opposite transition (react to 1st character of word, rather than last) uses less logic and doesn't care about leading or trailing SP or punctuation being present or not... Jus' sayin'...

I suggest you explore the world of “finite state automata”
Here with two states :
1 : in a word
2 : out a word
... after that count the number of transitions from in to out
More details is something like the next algorithm, a 2 state machine.
I suppose a word contents only letters.
If you have more rules you probably need more states.
In this graph circles content state values and arrows are transitions
Each arrow have one or more actions associated.

Let's have 
    "t" your array of char
    "state", the state of the automate (integer)
    "i", the char index (integer)
    "nb_word", word counter (integer)
    isalpha(character c) return true if c is an upper or lower letter 

//    INIT VALUES
state <- 0
nb_word <- 0
i <- 0

// Iteration

while ( not endofString(t[i]) )
|   if (isalpha(t[i]) 
|   |   state <- 1
|   else
|   |   if(state == 1)
|   |   |   nb_word <- nb_word + 1
|   |   |   state <- 0
|   |   -
|   -
|   i <- i + 1
-

I suggest this bedside reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

I think building a full state machine, even one as simple as this, is total overkill for an introductory homework.

It does feel a little bit advanced for where I’m currently at, but it’s good to know what’s out there!

Yeah, you did express you were new. But, essentially - it's keeping state. If in a word, continue, remember you are in a word. When you exit a word, increment. And then remember you exited from a word. Enter a word.. increment.. I think you get the idea. State management.

Thanks for explaining in more detail @Crosility.

@ Dúthomhas
I think this is a good example to introduce this concept

Algorithm is "off by one". "Hello" would be counted as 0 words... The UV's only demonstrate the low QC of this website...

You are counting the wrong thing.
You should be counting every time the character changes from a “non-word character” to a “word character”.
Notice how the definition is in terms of whether or not you have a “word character”.
In other words (pun!), don’t count characters. Count boundaries.

Interesting. That makes sense, though I’m not too sure how I’d go about that. I’m wondering if I’m over-engineering this though and I just need to ignore punctuation altogether and count only spaces (but ignore subsequent spaces in a row — so I don’t double count if there are two spaces after a period for instance). It’s fair to assume that a space signifies that the preceding word has ended, right? I’m sure there are edge cases, but this is meant to be a beginner exercise after all!

Not quite. A not-word-character followed by a word-character signifies a new word. You will need to look at two characters at a time (either the current and the next, or the previous and the current). You can do this with the same loop you have above.

Just have two flag variables:

Whether the current character is a separater (e.g. is_sep)
Whether the previous character was a separater (e.g. was_sep)

A word count transition occurs when is_sep is set but was_sep is not.
Special case for a string that has no trailing separater (e.g. hello)

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
count_words(const char *text)
{
    int word_count = 0;

    int was_sep = 1;

    for (int i = 0;  text[i] != 0;  ++i) {
        int chr = text[i];

        // word separaters are whitespace or ".?!"
        int is_sep = isspace(chr);
        if (! is_sep)
            is_sep = (chr == '.') || (chr == '?') || (chr == '!');

        // count words
        // we don't want to double count (e.g. "abc<sp><sp>def")
        if (is_sep && (! was_sep))
            ++word_count;

        // remember the current character state for the next round
        was_sep = is_sep;
    }

    // handle case where there is _no_ trailing "." et. al.
    if (! was_sep)
        ++word_count;

    return word_count;
}

void
test(const char *text)
{

    printf("%d: '%s'\n",count_words(text),text);
}

int
main(void)
{

    test("hello world.");
    test("hello   world .");
    test("   hello   world .");
    test("   hello   world");
    test("hello");

    return 0;
}


Here is the program output:
2: 'hello world.'
2: 'hello   world .'
2: '   hello   world .'
2: '   hello   world'
1: 'hello'


The annotations are really helpful, thanks.

For a basic, beginner's challenge like this, the simplest solution is to provide the full solution for the OP to learn from. SO tries to insist on a "Minimum Reproducible Example" in questions for clarity. Same standard should apply to SO answers.
To avoid all problems arising from leading and/or trailing whitespace and/or punctuation, you have to see that the solution is to detect the beginning (i.e. first letter) of each "word". Terminating '.' or SP or '\n' is/are then irrelevant to the algorithm.
Embedded hyphens ("know-how") and apostrophes ("Jane's") are to be considered part of their associated "word". More complexity can be added to detect and avoid counting hyphens as separators ("boy - girl"), if needed.
Further, the OP's example seems to wish to consider " 8 " to be a "word" for the purposes of counting. For this, isdigit() is also required.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // isalpha() isdigit()

int wc( char *s ) {
    int inword = 0, wc = 0;
    char ch;

    for( int i = 0; ( ch = s[i] ) != '\0'; i++ )
        if( isalpha((unsigned char)ch)
        ||  isdigit((unsigned char)ch)
        ||  ch == '\''
        ||  ch == '-' ) {
            wc += !inword; // count transitions INTO words
            inword = 1; // now in a word...
        } else inword = 0;

    return wc;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *str = "This should be 8 words. But it isn't.";

    printf( "%s\n", str );
    printf( "wc = %d\n", wc( str ) );

    return 0;
}

Output:
This should be 8 words. But it isn't.
wc = 8 // Seems to be, given the definition of "words" including digits

The OP should consider whether-or-not 'underscore' ('_') is a pseudo-letter for their purposes.
Is "whether-or-not" one word, or three? Hmmm...

Thanks for this. I ended up creating a not_a_word variable and passing in an array of characters that I wanted to count as delimiters, and then used strchr in a while loop to figure out whether to increment my words counter, and that did the trick for the purposes of passing the tests.

@quovixi Good news. Glad you achieved your goal, and made use of Standard Library function. Might want to look into and think about strspn() or strcspn(), too. Cheers...
